# I changed my /etc/pam.d/common-auth with failock and i can't login back into my vm, did I lose my VM?

Tags: pam

I followed this one to implement faillock in the common-auth, I'm not able to log back in to my VM, did i just lose my VM?

[How do I set up pam_faillock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403438/how-do-i-set-up-pam-faillock/1404228#1404228)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to boot into recovery mode and restore the common-auth from backup
For ubuntu on virtual box on my 2018 m1, I hit escape for recovery mode when restarting the VM