# pam_tally Issue while upgrading to 22.04 from 20.04

Tags: 20.04, 22.04

I am trying to upgrade to next LTS version. When I run
`sudo do-release-upgrade` facing below error. Did not get much help from google. Any help will be much appreciated?

```
You are using pam_tally or pam_tally2 in your configuration. 

The pam_tally and pam_tally2 modules have been removed from PAM. You 
are using one of these modules in your PAM configuration in 
/etc/pam.d. You must remove the uses of these modules before PAM can 
be upgraded; including these modules in your PAM configuration after 
the upgrade will stop users from being able to log into the system. 

Consider the pam_faillock module as a replacement for pam_tally. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
=== Command detached from window (Mon Mar  6 18:59:02 2023) ===
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Mon Mar  6 18:59:12 2023) ===
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any tool that will do this migration for you automagically - you will need to manually remove  uses of pam_tally / pam_tally2 from the files in `/etc/pam.d` and then (if you wish) set up pam_faillock - see for example [How do I set up pam_faillock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403438/how-do-i-set-up-pam-faillock)

Comment: Thanks, It worked after removing unwanted entires.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you guys, we were having trouble with updating the Openmedia (pam_tally, pam_tall2), removed the items found in /etc/pam.d (egrep -i pam_tally *).

I was able to upgrade the files and used the maintainer version.

I will continue to test but it is looking good.

Again, thank you.

Todd